# How to excute something what is inside a variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, execute, stored-functions

I have a problem what I can solve in PHP but I want to solve in MySQL. Basicley I have a stored function, `TASK_ASSIGN(id_task, operator)`.

I have an other function what `SELECT exec FROM tasks`. The tasks has a column exec, inside there I save `TASK_ASSIGN(id_task, operator)` format to execute.

I want to execute in a stored function or procedure if it is possible. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Check: [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) and [D.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Comment: @wchiquito thanks for the help, the solution was with the prepared statements. check the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a stored procedure with this source:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE $execute_function VARCHAR(100);

    -- Get the waiting function for execution
    SELECT `exec` INTO $execute_function FROM `tasks` WHERE `id_task` = '1';

    -- Create a session variable with the complete select
    SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT ",$execute_function," AS result");

    -- Execute the custom query
    PREPARE execute_query FROM @query; 
    EXECUTE execute_query;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE execute_query; 
END;
```

Thanks for [wchiquito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316440/wchiquito) for suggesting the Prepared Statements.